# How to update sitecore user with webforms for marketers ( Update Contact Details )

Tags: c#, forms, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm working on a Sitecore 8 Update 2 site.
I used web forms for marketers to create a login and register page. These worked fine and were easy to use. On the register form i was able to link fields on the form with fields on the selected user profile, nice and easy.

Now i want a page were user can edit their contact data.
However when i want to link the fields of the form I can only link them to facets. I have filled in the " User Profile " field of the form with my profile. So i would like to link these fields just as a register form does.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: If you want to update contact data you will have to update Facets this is how xDB works. Each bit of information needs to be updated via a facet .e.g `var personalInfo = Tracker.Current.Contact.GetFacet<Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Entities.IContactPersonalInfo>("Personal");
            personalInfo.FirstName =firstname;
            personalInfo.Surname = surname;`

Comment: @goldengrahams Would i then have to add facets for all the custom fields i've added to the profile ?

Comment: Yes, if want custom data in XDB you'll have to register the facet in the config and then WFFM should pick them up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update contact data you will have to update facets using the Update Contact Details Save Action - this is how xDB works and exerything is a facet. Each bit of information in xDB needs to be updated via a facet 
e.g. the Personal Info Facet

```
 var personalInfo = Tracker.Current.Contact.GetFacet<Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Entities.IContactPerso‌​nalInfo>("Personal"); 
 personalInfo.FirstName =firstname; 
 personalInfo.Surname = surname;
```

To register custom facets there's a good post here:

http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/getting-to-know-sitecore/posts/2014/09/introducing-contact-facets.aspx

Comment: I added a facet to the contact and i can now select it when using the "Update Contact Details" option. However when i check the value in the User Manager under the tab Profile the value isn't changed.

Do i miss a link between the facet and the profile field ? Or should it automaticly be connected if the facet and the profile field have the same name

Comment: The Profile on the user in the user manager runs of the the ASP.NET membership aspnet_profile table in the Core database and xDB is completely different - the data is in MongoDB. So you have to link the two together. I would use the asp net membership guid of a user as the identifier - you could use this in MongoDB to identify the user. Haven't checked but WFFM might do this automatically.

Comment: I have no experience working with MongoDB. So i'm having some problems visualizing what i would have to do. Do i download something like Robomongo and use that application to alter a field or ?

Comment: Nor do I really :) It's quite easy to pickup - it's all just json data.  Download Robomongo and connect to your local Mongo DB instance. When you're connected using RoboMongo, look in the xxx_analytics database - in here you will have a Contacts collection. Right click the collection and select "View documents". You'll be able to see your contacts in here. You shouldn't need to alter anything - it's just good to see what's actually happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Hope this helps - http://coreblimey.azurewebsites.net/sitecore-8-xdb-and-experience-profile-simplified/

Answer (score 0):

See the pictures below how you need to configure this.
The **Create User** save action needs to be configured to update user account and profile. NOTE the password field. You cannot change that this way. To change the password there is another action.

The **Update Contact Details** save action will update the XDB contact.

[Screencast pictures](https://www.screencast.com/t/F00Wzz4L)

Answer (score -1):

Basically, what you need is to use out-of-the-box "**Update Contact Details**" Save Action on your form, which will allow you to bind form fields to your contact's facets.

I have blogged a solution for this recently! 
Check this post for more details: https://broair.wordpress.com/2016/08/17/wffm-associate-form-fields-with-xdb-contact-facets/